# OData API is Unable to load the specified metadata resource / MetaDataException

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, web-config, odata

i am working on an API that should provide data from a SQL Server Database. Everything is working, when I request Metadata via Postman the result is correct, but when i want to show a table of the database or the values of a row in one of the tables, i get a huge error prompt which looks like this:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "innererror": {
        "message": "Fehler des Typs \"ObjectContent`1\" beim Serialisieren des Antworttexts für den Inhaltstyp \"application/json; odata.metadata=minimal\".",
        "type": "System.InvalidOperationException",
        "stacktrace": "",
        "internalexception": {
            "message": "Angeforderte Metadatenressource kann nicht geladen werden.",
            "type": "System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException",
            "stacktrace": "   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResources(String assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.CreateResourceLoader(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.SplitPaths(String paths)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0()\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetArtifactLoader(DbConnectionOptions effectiveConnectionOptions)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetMetadataWorkspace(DbConnectionOptions effectiveConnectionOptions)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace()\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection()\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor, ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory objectQueryExecutionPlanFactory, Translator translator, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()\r\n   bei Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteResourceSet(IEnumerable enumerable, IEdmTypeReference resourceSetType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   bei Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteObjectInline(Object graph, IEdmTypeReference expectedType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   bei Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteObject(Object graph, Type type, ODataMessageWriter messageWriter, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   bei Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.ODataOutputFormatterHelper.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, IEdmModel model, ODataVersion version, Uri baseAddress, MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType, IWebApiUrlHelper internaUrlHelper, IWebApiRequestMessage internalRequest, IWebApiHeaders internalRequestHeaders, Func`2 getODataMessageWrapper, Func`2 getEdmTypeSerializer, Func`2 getODataPayloadSerializer, Func`1 getODataSerializerContext)\r\n   bei Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__22.MoveNext()"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Sorry, i know it's in german but it basically says that there is a MetadataException and that the requested MetaData resource could not be loaded.

From what i researched and found so far, that means there is a problem with my connectionString, but i tried 1001 different fixes that i found online and none of them seemed to work.

I would be really happy if someone could take a look at my connectionString down below and tell me if there is somthing wrong with it, and if not what else could cause that error... try to explain it easily tho i am a beginner :)

My connectionString:

```
<add name="modul335" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Database.csdl|res://*/Models.Database.ssdl|res://*/Models.Database.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LAPTOP-ST7EUDF4\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=modul335;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Best way is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Capture results with Postman which is working.  Then repeat with c# code.  Compare the first Request html message between working and non working.  Make c# look exactly like postman.

Comment: @jdweng and what is this gonna help me with?

Answer (score 0):

**So i finally fixed the problem, and it was surprisingly easy: i modified the "have you tried turning it off and on again?" and deleted my models and then added them again. and voilà, everything works fine i think :)**